# SQL query returns values without taking into account tones over letters

Tags: python, sql, mysql, string

I have the following query against a database of Chinese characters, where `py` -- is the transcription.

```py
cursor.execute('''' SELECT * FROM words_ch WHERE py LIKE %s''', (str(word),'')))
```

As we know there in Chinese are several tones: ā, á, ǎ, à etc.

I expected to get strings where py == māo, but I get strings with all tones māo máo máo mǎo mào.

What is this related to?

Is it possible to fix it so that the query accuracy is higher?

Comment: Why do you pass a tuple `(str(word),'')` of 2 values whereas there is only one `%s` ?

Comment: The duplicate explains why you need utf8 on the server and connection string, you van check the documentation how to set utf8 in the connection dtring